# Background colour not showing up in laravel 7

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm trying to create a simple laravel app using the latest laravel 7. I followed the instruction but somehow when I tried to run the app the colour are not showing up? No error show up and I'm clueless on how to fix it.

`app.scss`

```
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1000vh;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(121,9,111,1) 100%, rgba(4,2,58,1) 100%);
}
```

`app.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

 <!-- script -->
    <script> scr="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Font -->

<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

    @yield('content')
    
</body>
</html>
```

`welcome.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

    <div class="w-100 h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <h1>Task App</h1>
    </div>

@endsection
```

This is the tutorial that I followed
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDCY277XBh8&list=LL_rwMhjYKPXXDlVH-6MFoqg&index=6&t=0s

colour not showing up

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you followed what/which instructions?

Comment: I have updated the link

Comment: does this video go into compiling assets? and there is an entire section in the Laravel docs about this stuff

Answer (score 0):

css file name `app.scss`

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.scss') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```